# Sharing project properties between different modules in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Inside an Android studio project, I am writing 2 Android applications that share a library coded by myself.

```
Project /  
 - app1 /  
 - app2 /  
 - mylibrary /
```

So, in the build.gradle of app1 and app2, I need to include a dependency for compiling mylibrary.

```
dependencies {  
    // Compile shared library  
    compile project(':mylibrary')  
    // Local binary dependency  
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  
}
```

So far, everything is working fine.

Then, I am building both app1 and app2 with 2 different scripts and I am including some custom parameters during each building. For example, the building script for app1 will be:

```
cd app1

../gradlew assembleRelease -PversionCode=$VERSION_CODE -PversionName=$VERSION_NAME -PWS_URL=$WS_URL
```

I can access to versionName, versionCode and WS_URL parameters from propject.property in the build.gradle of "app1", but the problem consists in I cannot from the build.gradle of "mylibrary" and I need to share that information

Is there any way to share this information in both "app1" and "mylibrary"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of accessing properties of another project is by using the `project(:name)` method, where `:name` is the identifier for the project that you want to access. You can find more info about it in [Chapter 57. Multi-project Builds - 57.1.2](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

In your specific case, you can make your 'app1' use properties that are defined in 'mylibrary' by doing something like `project(:mylibrary).hasProperty('something')` and `project(:mylibrary).property('something')`', or access properties from 'app1' in 'mylibrary' by doing `project(:app1)` instead.

You can also store the `-PversionCode` in the `ext` closure to make the code cleaner and easier to use (e.g. `project(:app1).ext.versionCode`.